# Use Group By in order to remove duplicates

Tags: c#, linq, collections, duplicates

I am looking for a simple way of removing duplicates without having to implement the class IComparable, having to override GetHashCode etc..

I think this can be achieved with linq. I have the class:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public ing Age;
}
```

I have a list of about 500 People `List<Person> someList = new List<Person()`

now I want to remove people with the same name and if there is a duplicate I want to keep the person that had the greater age. In other words if I have the list:

```
Name----Age---
Tom,     24  |
Alicia,  22  |
Alicia,  12  |
```

I will like to end up with:

```
Name----Age---
Tom,     24  |
Alicia,  22  |
```

How can I do this with a query? My list is not that long so I don't want to create a hash set nor implement the IComparable interface. It will be nice if I can do this with a linq query.

I think this can be done with the groupBy extension method by doing something like:

```
var people = // the list of Person
person.GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Where(x=>x.Count()>1)
      ...    // select the person that has the greatest age...
```

Comment: No need for a `Where` clause - if there is only one person with a particular name, that person will have the greatest age.

Answer (score 8):

```
people
  .GroupBy(p => p.Name)
  .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age).First())
```

This will work across different Linq providers. If this is just Linq2Objects, and speed is important (usually, it isn't) consider using one of the many MaxBy extensions found on the web (here's [Skeet](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MaxBy.cs?r=741b3d8f3a16aa16615c4fa546d4b547cfed1a8f)'s) and replacing

```
g.OrderByDescending(p => p.Age).First()
```

with

```
g.MaxBy(p => p.Age)
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be trivially easy so long as you first create a helper function `MaxBy` that is capable of selecting the item from a sequence who's selector is largest.  Unfortunately the `Max` function in LINQ won't work as we want to select the item from the sequence, not the selected value.

```
var distinctPeople = people.GroupBy(person => person.Name)
   .Select(group => group.MaxBy(person => person.Age));
```

And then the implementation of `MaxBy`:

```
public static TSource MaxBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? Comparer<TKey>.Default;

    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            throw new ArgumentException("Source must have at least one item");

        var maxItem = iterator.Current;
        var maxKey = keySelector(maxItem);

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            var nextKey = keySelector(iterator.Current);
            if (comparer.Compare(nextKey, maxKey) > 0)
            {
                maxItem = iterator.Current;
                maxKey = nextKey;
            }
        }

        return maxItem;
    }
}
```

Note that while you can achieve the same result by sorting the sequence and then taking the first item, doing so is less efficient in general than doing just one pass with a max function.

Comment: it's trivially easy even without a helper function.  ;)

Comment: @MichaelBray If you're referring to spender's solution, the issue there is that you shouldn't have to sort the entire sequence just to get the largest; this avoids that.  If, in your specific case, you don't care, then that's fine, but in the general case to always sort your data in order to get the item who's property has the largest value isn't always appropriate.

Comment: Servy: a valid point.  You should clarify your post so it's clear that this is the advantage you are gaining by the code provided.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to be simple:

```
var retPeople = new List<Person>;
        foreach (var p in person)
        {
            if(!retPeople.Contains(p))
            {
                retPeople.Add(p);
            }
        }
```

Making Person to implement IComparable

Answer (score -1):

I got rid of my last answer because I realized it was too slow and was too complicated. Here is the solution that makes a little more sense

```
        var peoplewithLargestAgeByName =
            from p in people
            orderby p.Name
            group p by p.Name into peopleByName
            select peopleByName.First ( );
```

This is the same solution as the solution @spender contributed, but with the linq syntax.

Comment: Your query is selecting a bunch of ages, not people.